# Display JSON in blade table

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-collection

My laravel 5.3 web site receives a response in JSON format:

```
{#356 ▼
  +"eventsreport": {#355 ▼
    +"employ": array:6 [▼
      0 => {#329 ▼
        +"@id_staff_external": ""
        +"@id_staff_internal": "6655"
        +"@tab_n": ""
        +"@fio": "Иванов Иван Иваныч"
        +"@appoint_id_external": ""
        +"@subdiv_id_external": ""
        +"@appoint_id_internal": "5094"
        +"@subdiv_id_internal": "6652"
        +"@appoint_name": "Учащийся"
        +"@subdiv_name": "5 Б класс"
        +"events": array:8 [▼
          0 => {#327 ▼
            +"@id_staff_external": ""
            +"@id_staff_internal": "6655"
            +"@datetimeevent": "27.04.2017 9:05:05 PM"
            +"@typepass": "Выход"
          }
          1 => {#313 ▶}
          2 => {#323 ▶}
          3 => {#317 ▶}
          4 => {#316 ▶}
          5 => {#314 ▶}
          6 => {#328 ▶}
          7 => {#321 ▶}
        ]
      }
      1 => {#330 ▼
        +"@id_staff_external": ""
        +"@id_staff_internal": "6642"
        +"@tab_n": ""
        +"@fio": "Ивановбаа Иван1баа Иваныч1баа"
        +"@appoint_id_external": ""
        +"@subdiv_id_external": ""
        +"@appoint_id_internal": "6644"
        +"@subdiv_id_internal": "5089"
        +"@appoint_name": "Учащиеся"
        +"@subdiv_name": "5 А класс"
      }
      2 => {#331 ▼
        +"@id_staff_external": ""
        +"@id_staff_internal": "6658"
        +"@tab_n": ""
        +"@fio": "Петров Петр Петрович"
        +"@appoint_id_external": ""
        +"@subdiv_id_external": ""
        +"@appoint_id_internal": "5094"
        +"@subdiv_id_internal": "6652"
        +"@appoint_name": "Учащийся"
        +"@subdiv_name": "5 Б класс"
        +"events": array:6 [▶]
      }
      3 => {#338 ▶}
      4 => {#339 ▶}
      5 => {#354 ▶}
    ]
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to display this data in blade table as per below format:

```
fio|appoint_name|subdiv_name|datetimeevent|typepass
```

As you see there can be no/one/more than one rows for any of the `employs`.
My controller has this piece of code:

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri'=> config('app.schools.'.$school_id).$rep_name,
    'query' => ['dFrom'=>$dfrom,
                'dTo'=>$dto,
                'depId'=>$dep_id_perco
                ],
    'timeout' => 10.0 
    ]);
$response = $client->request('GET');
$results = json_decode($response->getbody()->getcontents());
$collection = new Collection($results);
```

I know that now I can pass `$collection` to my view. But how should I loop through each `employ` of my `$collection` in blade?

Answer (score 0):

Try looping inside your `tbody` like this:

```
 <tbody>
       @foreach($collection as $eventreport)
         @foreach($eventreport as $employ)
            <tr>
               <td> {{$employ->fio}}  </td>
               <td> {{$employ->appoint_name}}  </td>
               <td> {{$employ->subdiv_name}}  </td>
               <td> {{$employ->datetimeevent}}  </td>
               <td> {{$employ->typepass}}  </td>
            </tr>
         @endforeach
       @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

Comment: In this case I am getting an exception: 
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\secureschool\resources\views\reports\filo.blade.php)

Comment: One more thing to mention - I do not have any model corresponding to this $collection.